# DSE Spark Shell Authentication

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I have a DSE 4.5 installation with spark running. I need some help in passing the username / password of cassandra cluster from Spark Shell.

I have added these properties to conf/spark-default.conf file

```
spark.cassandra.auth.username=user
spark.cassandra..auth.password=pass
```

And start up my spark shell using

```
dse spark
```

But still seeing the error when I try sc.cassandraTable

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /11.111.11.11:9042: Host /11.111.11.11:9042 requires authentication, but no authenticator found in Cluster configuration
    at com.datastax.driver.core.AuthProvider$1.newAuthenticator(AuthProvider.java:38)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.initializeTransport(Connection.java:138)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:111)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:432)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:216)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:171)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1104)
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you can execute this command

```
dse spark -Dcassandra.username=user -Dcassandra.password=pass
```

ref:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/sec/secIntrnlAuth.html?scroll=secItrnlAuth__authentication-for-hadoop-tools

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
dse -u cassandra -p cassandra spark
```